# Mootools breaking jQuery functionality

Tags: jquery, mootools, conflict

Having an issue with Mootools breaking my slideshow scripts jQuery functionality. Cannot pinpoint what is happening, but particularly in Firefox it is destroying the functionality and making my browser unresponsive.

http://newsite.matthewruddy.com/

Can anyone give me any idea what I am doing wrong? I've used jQuery.noConflict() where appropriate but no dice. Firebug doesn't seem to be showing any errors, and when the MooTools script is disabled all is fine. Also, it seems to be less troublesome in other browsers, but still happens the odd time in Safari, Chrome, etc. Most of the time it works fine (very hit and miss).

jQuery is being loaded before MooTools, but the scripting my plugin loads is in the footer, after MooTools is loaded. Can't really work around this, as with Wordpress it is the only way I can get the scripts to load only on pages the slideshows are used on.

Comment: It's not usually the best idea to try and use two JS libraries together since they'll really step on each others' toes. Since jQuery and Mootools pretty much do the same thing, it might be better to just go with one or the other.

Comment: @robbrit was going to upvote until "Since jQuery and Mootools pretty much do the same thing". Take a look at http://jqueryvsmootools.com/. With that being said, I agree choose which works best for your programming habits and project needs. if you must use both, Put jQuery in noConflict mode and with both libs DO NOT USE $ use jQuery for jQuery and document.id for mootools

Comment: I'm not using the two intentionally. My plugin (the slideshow) uses jQuery. A lot of users use a particular plugin that uses MooTools, and they have reported to me that it is causing my plugin to malfunction. This particular plugin also loads its scripts on all pages (MooTools and two others), so I'm trying to figure out what I can do to prevent the errors caused. Quite a lot of users have reported issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a conflict with the `load` event. The Riva Slider plugin triggers `load` on a object, but instead of the jQuery `load` event firing the mootools `load` fires instead. For some reason, this causes mootools to retrieve the index of your site via AJAX over and over and over again, which is causing FF to freeze. I would try getting jQuery to load before mootools, or just dump one of them. It's really not a good idea to mix frameworks.

[image: Stack Trace]

EDIT: Also, you say that you load jQuery before mootools, but you don't. mootools is loaded in the `<head>`, while jQuery isn't loaded until the bottom of the page, right before the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. It was a mistake to say that jQuery is being loaded before; in this case it isn't. My previous setup (local MAMP setup) had jQuery loading before MooTools, but the issue was the same. Is there anything I can do to prevent the MooTools load from firing? I would prefer to not have to advise users not to use my plugin when this plugin is being used also, especially since a lot of users do.

Comment: @MatthewRuddy I don't know much about MooTools. Maybe you could check in your plugin to see if MooTools is loaded, and if so, remove any events that may have been registered by MooTools. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:removeEvents

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery before Mootools here is an example script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //no conflict jquery
    jQuery.noConflict();
    //jquery stuff
    (function($) {
        $('p').css('color','#ff0000');
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moo1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //moo stuff
    window.addEvent('domready',function() {
        $$('p').setStyle('border','1px solid #fc0');
    });
</script>
```

> `<p>This is a paragraph.</p>`